# macOS Big Sur 11.6 - How can I rename multiple files at once that don't follow a pattern?

Tags: macos, applescript, javascript

Is there a way to rename multiple files that follow a pseudo numeric pattern to names that do not follow a pattern, maybe from a list of names in a document?

For example, I have multiple images from a camera currently named "picture1.jpg", "picture2.jpg", "picture5.jpg", and "picture9.jpg" and would like to change them to "Bob.jpg", "Janie.jpg", "Lane.jpg", and "Jennifer.jpg".

I expect it has to be something in the Script Editor, I'm just not familiar enough to come up with the code myself.

Comment: I cannot think of any use-case where setting up this as an automated task would be any quicker than just doing it manually.

Comment: The file names I used are for example only.  I actually have over 700 files that need to be renamed from numbers to my list of peoples' names, and will be doing this regularly.  Being able to let the computer use the list to rename the pictures will be extremely efficient.

Comment: If you have a non-contiguous input list & a non-contiguous output list, automating it will mean typing out both lists of names. I could see the case for manually lifting all of one output name to a new folder, but then you'd still be juggling with non-contiguous number schemes - input: photo1, photo4, output: john1, john4 etc

Comment: [A Better Finder Rename](https://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/index.html) can rename & renumber, and can rename from a list - but you'd still need to generate the list manually, of course. - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOB5K.png

Comment: The answer is yes but you don't provide any useful information. You don't say how you determine which files get renamed to what. Does picture9 become Jennifer because it's 'picture9' or because it's the fourth picture in the sequence? For these 700+ files, are there 700+ names in your list? Will next week's files/list follow the same pattern?